# Third party libraries isn't copied to the project output although it is set to Copy Local

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dependencies

I have a dependency problem with Visual Studio 2008 that in a solution there are two projects *ProjectA* and *ProjectB*. *ProjectA* has a reference for *ProjectB* and *ProjectB* has a reference for a third library party which is set to **Copy Local**.

Now, when *ProjectA* is built, the third party library which is referenced by *ProjectB* has not been copied to the *ProjectA* output.

Did I miss anything or this is the default behavior?
The problem I'm facing is when I deploy the application in a machine which doesn't have this third party library in the GAC it will throw a dependency exception.

Comment: Erm, wait, this only goes wrong on a machine you deployed to, not on your own machine?  Then it is a deployment problem.

Comment: I think it may be included in the Project B's library itself

Comment: @JayantVarshney Yes, it's included in ProjectB, but I needed to be with ProjectA for deployment

Comment: also add in the reference of the project A..

Comment: @HansPassant No, the problem exists on my machine. Libraries are not copied to ProjectA output.

Comment: @JayantVarshney, Is this the solution? Is it not a problem and it is been fixed as this always?

The problem with me is that it is a WPF xBap project which did not accept this solution because it makes hashing for libraries.

Comment: @JayantVarshney, While ProjectA has a reference for ProjectB, and ProjectB has a reference for this third party library. I expect that when the ProjectB is copied to the ProjectA output, all its dependencies should be copied with it. Got my idea?

Comment: well I got you... and have no idea about this problem.... but once you can try to search an option in the project or solution properties

Answer (score 1):

The MSBuild behavior is pretty straight forward.  It will copy any dependencies of a referenced project's output assembly when:

- Copy Local is set to True on the reference
- The dependency can be found from the metadata of the reference.  Note that this will prevent any dependency from getting copied if it is loaded in an unusual way, like Assembly.Load()
- The dependency is present in the same directory as the reference at build time.  There is no warning if it is not present for any reason
- The dependency is not registered in the GAC

If you missed any of the first three bullets then you also won't be able to debug your solution.  Watch out for the forth bullet, it appears to be a match with the last sentence in your question.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. Yes, the library is registered in GAC and it should be in my development machine. What should I do to get over the problem?

Comment: It is entirely unclear why it needs to be in the GAC.  But clearly if that's important then it needs to be in the GAC on the target machine as well.  Just as it wasn't automatically put in the GAC on your dev machine, it won't be automatically put in the GAC on the deployment machine.  You'll need to create an installer to get this done, simple with a Setup project.  Or run the installer of that library on the target machine as well, if any.

Comment: I cannot install the library on the client machine's GAC because it's an xBap WPF application. Any other solutions !!